# Pickup a array which have matching of more than 4 words from user input

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filter, find

I am working on a project in which the user input a value and get an array which have the matching key words from user input

I want that if any word match with a length of more than 4 word then it show that array

```
var myArray = ['my name is alex', 'my age is 20 years', 'and so on.... ']
```

For example if user type 
what is your name 
then it should return 
My name is Alex

And same with the age stuff and others

Comment: So you want to compare one big user input (one big `string`) with some matching words from a list? That would need a string separation, a dictionary with all the words you want to scan/compare and maybe phrases you want to add to those words inside the dictionary.

Comment: Yes! Can you help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution in Stackblitz, checkout console:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-n1vu8v

Some setup. Using a map to save the things you are looking for and the result you want to have in your `myArray`. `userInput` is the string/text you are going to scan.

```js
var userInput = 'A very long text. Hello my name is Alex. I am from Germany.'

let map = new Map();

map.set('Alex', 'His name is alex');
map.set('Germany', 'He is from Germany');

var cleanedInput = cleanInput(userInput)
var stringArray = splitInput(cleanedInput);
var foundHits = findHits(stringArray);
console.log(foundHits);
```

First of all you need to remove all the special characters. Depend on what language you are using it will be different ones. Using an regular expression here.

```js
function cleanInput(userInput) {
  return  userInput.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')
}
```

After I cleaned the user input. You need to split the long string array. I splitted the text by scanning for all the whitespaces.

```js
function splitInput(cleanedInput)
{
  var stringArray = cleanedInput.split(" ");

  return stringArray;
};
```

After that you can iterate through the returned array by a normal for loop. Just try to get the string from the map. If there is no key entry in the map, there is not hit and it will be null. If its not null you can add the result of the map to your `myArray` - your final result.

```js
function findHits(stringArray){
  var myArray = [];
  
  for(let i=0; i<stringArray.length; i++) {
    var hit = map.get(stringArray[i]);
    if (hit != null){
      myArray.push(map.get(stringArray[i]))
      console.log(stringArray[i])
    }
  }
  return myArray;
}
```

Notes: It's a very simple solution. You need to be careful with male, female and *. Also you need to avoid false positive. Something like "My mom is from Germany", so "Alex" isn't from Germany. To scan years for an age. You need find that age. Because you can't scan every number and hope its an "age". And so on. What you are trying to achieve is some serious logical work. Or you can use an already developed AI.

Comment: Thanks bro for the help